# system.webServer/security/authorization in web.config how to migrate to aspcore

Tags: asp.net-web-api, authorization, asp.net-core-identity

I'm using a asp.net webapp which uses system.webServer in web.config and have a list of user accounts as roles.

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <security>
      <authorization>
        <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
        <add accessType="Allow" roles="MOON\USER1" />
        <add accessType="Allow" roles="MARS\USER2" />
      </authorization>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

and to achieve this authorization in asp.net core i tried to use different approaches and none seems working. What is the right and best way in asp.net core to implement authorization of web app to load for restricted users.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you managed to find the solution to your issue but the first problem in that config file is that the auth rules are matched in order. All your requests are matching the deny first and you never get to evaluate the access for USER1 and USER2.